# Finding number of mismatches between two strings

Tags: java, string, arrays, mismatch

I am needed find number of mismatching characters between two strings. Currently i m doing it by converting  strings into char Arrays and comparing element by element.

Is there any other way to achieve above requirement.

***Note:*** consider  string as lower case

***Inputs :***

input

utput

***Output :***

2

Comment: There are other ways, but none better.

Comment: Just be careful with words of differing sizes.

Comment: Your variant is good. What output for: "input" "iAnput" do you expect?

Comment: Do you really just want the number of mismatches or something more advanced like the edit-distance between the words? just curious...

Comment: I agree. If you compare ```a12345``` and ```12345```, do you have one difference, or 5 differences? You need to process the entire string and shift as necessary to align similar contiguous characters.

Comment: ignoring the character-case and just comparing two strings ,no need to adjustments

Comment: @Theja: then I guess there is no better/easier way than what you already do...

Answer (score 1):

`StringUtils` in Apache commons.lang has a [method](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for getting the Levenshtein distance of two strings.

Comment: that's nice, but definately not what he wants... unless it is possible to set the operation costs manually and set "delete" and "insert" to a very high value. but even then it would be a big overhead.

Comment: @Baz, i would think it would work better as Levenstein distance defines the number of operations required to convert one string into another, in essence, this is what the OP is doing

Comment: but levenstein allows deletion and insertion. that is not what the OP wants. he wants the hamming distance between the words. that does not mean, that i personally would not prefer levenstein

Comment: @Baz, agreed, just think the OP needs to define his objective more clearly :)

Comment: @codeBrickie Thanks .., but it looks like one of the string get modified to find mismatches, Input strings not supposed to change

Comment: @Theja Where did you get this info from?

Comment: @codeBrickie its like some home work question. i  did that by using char arrays. I m wondering that is there any other possibilities to achive it. so, i posted here

Comment: @Theja I meant why you suppose that the method I mentioned changes the input string. In fact, it doesn't. And if your questions are homework questions, please tag them as such.

Comment: @CodeBrickie ok.,I m tagging it now.

Answer (score 0):

If the two string are of different size the following code you return the total mismatch of alphabets.

You can try this -

```
    String ip1 = "input"; // input1
    String ip2 = "utput"; // input2
    int count = 0; // difference in string
    String ipx2 = ip2;
    for (int j = 0; j <= ip2.length(); j++) {
        int value = ip1.indexOf(ipx2);
        if (value != -1) {
            if (("").equals(ipx2)) { // if the second string is blank after continous reducing
                count = ip1.length() + ip2.length();
            } else {
                count = ip1.length() + ip2.length() - 2 * ipx2.length();
            }
            break;
        } else {
            count = ip1.length() + ip2.length(); // if there is no match at all
        }
        ipx2 = ip2.substring(j);
    }
    System.out.println("" + count);
}
```

You will have to check whether the inputs have some data or not. I have not done that check.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you are describing, but it is the simplest way of implementing:

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) if(str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)) counter++;
```

They can be fit on just two lines of code, without explicitly creating a whole new character array.

Comment: only ok if both strings are of the same length.  add this...
  if (str1.length() <= i) {differences++; } else {